# Доступ к public SharedPreferences из друго класса

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Подскажите такой вопрос: в классе `B` сохраняются данные в  `SharedPreferences`:

```
public SharedPreferences mPreferencesregistr = null; 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   mPreferencesregistr = getSharedPreferences("firstrun", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  

   if (!issaveFiiled()) {
      mPreferencesregistr.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", true).apply();
      SaveData.this.finish();  
   }
 }
```

в классе `A` необходимо сделать проверку:

```
if (mPreferencesregistr.getBoolean("firstrun", false)) {
    uploadImage();
}
else{//условие}
```

как правильно получить значение переменной `mPreferencesregistr`, если `mPreferencesregistr` в другом классе.

Comment: Просто в другой активити получите новый экземпляр `SharedPreferences` с такими же параметрами (`mPreferencesregistr = getSharedPreferences("firstrun", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`) и обращайтесь к нему.

Answer (score 3):

Храните настроки в `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`. Они вам будут доступны во всем приложении

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
preferences.getBoolean("firstrun", false)
```

а положить туда так:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);;
Editor ed = pref.edit();
ed.putBoolean("firstrun", true);
ed.apply();
```

Comment: а как положить туда `mPreferencesregistr.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", true).apply();`
?

Comment: Добавил в ответ описание того, как туда положить данные

Answer (score 1):

Неплохой вариант сделать Singleton класс PreferencesManager, в котором описать все взаимодействия с SharedPreferences.

```
public class PreferencesManager {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static PreferencesManager INSTANCE = null;
    private final String USER_TOKEN_KEY = "USER_TOKEN_KEY";



    private PreferencesManager(Context context) {
        this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.myappcompany.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static PreferencesManager getInstance(Context context) {

        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (PreferencesManager.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = new PreferencesManager(context);
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void saveToken(String token) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(this.USER_TOKEN_KEY, token).commit();
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(this.USER_TOKEN_KEY, "empty");
    }
}
```

Соответственно, получаем доступ к объекту в какой-либо активити так:

```
PreferencesManager preferencesManager = PreferencesManager.getInstance(context);
```

И обращаемся к интересующим нас методам:

```
 //Допустим, хотим проверить токен и, 
 //если новый токен не равен старому, сохраним новый
String newToken; 
if (preferencesManager.getToken().equals(newToken)) {
    preferencesManager.saveToken(newToken);
}
```

Comment: А зачем это делать, если любой экземпляр SharedPreference с аналогичными параметрами получает доступ к одному и тому же файлу настроек?